# Build failed for python 3.5.1 on Cygwin (Could not allocate TLS entry)

Tags: python, makefile, cygwin

I've been trying to make python build from sources through cygwin64 on windows7. I've ran into some issues I've been able to fix but I'm stuck on this one.

I get a "Fatal python error: Could not allocate TLS entry".

Here's the end of the build logs.

```
gcc -c -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -   fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -Werror=declaration-after-statement   -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/home/mcharron/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/include  -I/home/mcharron/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
  -DHGVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
  -DHGTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
  -DHGBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
  -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
gcc -L/home/mcharron/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib  -L/home/mcharron/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib  -o Programs/_freeze_importlib Programs/_freeze_importlib.o Modules/getbuildinfo.o Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Parser/myreadline.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/tokenizer.o Objects/abstract.o Objects/accu.o Objects/boolobject.o Objects/bytes_methods.o Objects/bytearrayobject.o Objects/bytesobject.o Objects/cellobject.o Objects/classobject.o Objects/codeobject.o Objects/complexobject.o Objects/descrobject.o Objects/enumobject.o Objects/exceptions.o Objects/genobject.o Objects/fileobject.o Objects/floatobject.o Objects/frameobject.o Objects/funcobject.o Objects/iterobject.o Objects/listobject.o Objects/longobject.o Objects/dictobject.o Objects/odictobject.o Objects/memoryobject.o Objects/methodobject.o Objects/moduleobject.o Objects/namespaceobject.o Objects/object.o Objects/obmalloc.o Objects/capsule.o Objects/rangeobject.o Objects/setobject.o Objects/sliceobject.o Objects/structseq.o Objects/tupleobject.o Objects/typeobject.o Objects/unicodeobject.o Objects/unicodectype.o Objects/weakrefobject.o Python/_warnings.o Python/Python-ast.o Python/asdl.o Python/ast.o Python/bltinmodule.o Python/ceval.o Python/compile.o Python/codecs.o Python/dynamic_annotations.o Python/errors.o Python/frozenmain.o Python/future.o Python/getargs.o Python/getcompiler.o Python/getcopyright.o Python/getplatform.o Python/getversion.o Python/graminit.o Python/import.o Python/importdl.o Python/marshal.o Python/modsupport.o Python/mystrtoul.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/peephole.o Python/pyarena.o Python/pyctype.o Python/pyfpe.o Python/pyhash.o Python/pylifecycle.o Python/pymath.o Python/pystate.o Python/pythonrun.o Python/pytime.o Python/random.o Python/structmember.o Python/symtable.o Python/sysmodule.o Python/traceback.o Python/getopt.o Python/pystrcmp.o Python/pystrtod.o Python/pystrhex.o Python/dtoa.o Python/formatter_unicode.o Python/fileutils.o Python/dynload_shlib.o   Python/thread.o Modules/config.o Modules/getpath.o Modules/main.o Modules/gcmodule.o  Modules/_threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/_operator.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/atexitmodule.o  Modules/_stat.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/textio.o Modules/stringio.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/faulthandler.o  Modules/_tracemalloc.o Modules/hashtable.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o -ldl    -lm  
./Programs/_freeze_importlib \
./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py Python/importlib.h
./Programs/_freeze_importlib \
./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py Python/importlib_external.h
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TLS entry
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TLS entry
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFC2E0  001800719AC (000FFFFE3F4, 0000000ECD0, 7FEFCE851A8, 000FFFFDE50)
000FFFFC380  00180072F8B (00000000001, 00000000000, 000000000E8, 00000000000)
000FFFFC5D0  001801343E8 (001800C78E9, 00000000000, 7FEFD051430, 00000000000)
000FFFFC8C0  001801310BE (0000000D0BD, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00100636B54)
000FFFFC9E0  00180131539 (000FFFFC900, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000006)
000FFFFC9E0  0018013170A (0018020BB68, 00100636B3E, 001FFFFC9C8, 00000000000)
000FFFFC9E0  001801319CF (0018012CDEB, 00100637665, 001801523A0, 00000000000)
000FFFFC9E0  0010052A23E (0010052B4C7, 006000104D8, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000001  0010052CC6C (00000000000, 00000000000, 006000104D8, 00000000000)
00000000001  0010052AB86 (00000000000, 001801D4120, 000FFFFCBB0, 00100000001)
00180351670  001005A0241 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000030, 30001010100FF00)
000FFFFCCC0  00180047BD2 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  0018004591C (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  001800459B4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
Makefile:729 : la recette pour la cible « Python/importlib_external.h » a échouée
make: *** [Python/importlib_external.h] Aborted (core dump créé)
make: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
Makefile:733 : la recette pour la cible « Python/importlib.h » a échouée
make: *** [Python/importlib.h] Aborted (core dump créé)
```

Has anyone seen this or has a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the python3 cygwin source package ? May be the build setup can give you some hints

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?